# Magento 2.3.2 free shipping cart rule not working

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.2, free-shipping

I'm trying to set up a cart rule in which I only offer free shipping

I added a new cart rule with these conditions:

[image: cart rule conditions]

Then I try to place an order, I choose 'Flat rate' as shipping method, I apply 'Test3' coupon code, but I don't see any discount in shipping amount.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: did you add any conditions in the 'Conditions' section?

Comment: no condition, I would like to apply the rule aways, when I add 'test3' coupon to the cart

Comment: roger that. well, i don't have a 2.3.2 instance, but i tried on 2.4.1 and apparently something is wrong when using the flat rate - in cart it shows 0 shipping, but in the checkout, it's the rate you set on the method. However, this doesn't happen when using table rate. very interesting..

Comment: should we open an issue to magento developers' team?

Comment: let's try something before i promote this as an answer - change the ***Free Shipping*** dropdown to ***For matching items only*** and tell me if it's working for you. On m2.4.1 it works properly in combination with the flat rate, showing 0 shipping in both cart, checkout and submitted order.

Comment: can you check and see if this solves the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's the answer I needed. Thanks

Comment: ok great, I added the official answer :) consider marking this as a solution so others can see it too. cheers!

Comment: Please check my answer in here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/332124/35330 i sorted out how things work with the option 'For matching items only' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research on this and while the documentation [about free shipping for any order](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-free-shipping.html#example-1-free-shipping-for-any-order) says you should add *'For shipment with matching items'* value on the *'Free Shipping'* dropdown, I found that this doesn't work as is supposed to in our specific scenario as we want the shipping cost to be 0 on our delivery method.

Solution is to add set the **'Free Shipping'** dropdown to **'For matching items only'** value.

---

**Later edit:**
In the context of the thread https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/332124/35330 I explained all scenarios and the difference between the settings. The rule works fine **with both**  'For matching items only' and 'For shipment with matching items' options, but there is a difference in using them. Check that thread for more details (I added several explanatory screenshots too to prove the behavior).