# Magento 2 Free Shipping Coupon

Tags: magento2, free-shipping

in cart price rules, can someone explain whats the difference between

"For matching items only"

and

"For shipment with matching items"

i cant seem to find a good documentation for this. you set a condition on when it should apply. but whats the purpose on changing the free shipping dropdown.

this is located on the "Actions" section

Answer (score 3):

There is a combination of specific conditions for each scenario and the result will be somewhat different. In order to properly see the difference, my cart rule doesn't offer a discount amount, its discount when applied is actually the shipping cost, so here is how i set my rule:
[image]

So check my examples below in order to understand how this stuff works and what's the difference between the options:

1. Rule has **"For matching items only"** and it's conditioned to a specific product category in the 'Actions' section + Free Shipping delivery method is **disabled** + Flat Rate **enabled and set to fixed value 5** - in the cart page, you will see the following:
   [image]

As you can see, your shipping method remained 'Flat Rate', but the shipping cost displayed for it is 0.

2. Rule has **"For shipment with matching items"** and it's conditioned to a specific product category in the 'Actions' section + Free Shipping delivery method is **enabled** and has setting **Minimum Order Amount=99999** + Flat Rate **enabled and set to fixed value 5** - in the cart page, you will see the following:
   [image]

In this situation, we are restricting the visibility of the 'Free shipping' method by adding a huge number of items 99999 in the method's settings so it's not visible *until we satisfy the rules condition* (my condition says that items have to be from specific categories).

3. Rule has **"For matching items only"** and it's conditioned to a specific product category in the 'Actions' section + + Free Shipping delivery method is **enabled** and has setting **Minimum Order Amount=99999** + Flat Rate **enabled and set to fixed value 5** - in the cart page, you will see the following:
   [image]

As you can see here, your shipping method remained 'Flat Rate', but the shipping cost displayed for it is 0 AND the 'Free Shipping' method appears as well. So it's kinda the combination of the other two scenarios above.

---

Once I remove the items from my categories and add a new item from a different category, the rule is invalidated and only the 'Flat Rate' method appears alone:
[image]